# Physical MAC address in Linux

Tags: linux, ip, ip-address, mac-address

I searched google but couldn't find a valid solution.
I have a system where there are some physical MAC addresses and some MACs(~30) created by docker.
For my need, I need only Physical MACs.

So far I have come up with this solution:

```
ls  -l /sys/class/net/ | grep -v virtual
```

This returns only the physical address names from which I can get MAC address.

I wanted to know if it's possible to use `ip a` command with some options to filter out virtual MACs.

Comment: All Docker containers MAC address starts with the "vendor" id of '02:42:ac' which is not a registered vendor id.
You can try to filter them out using the following command:
 ```ip a | grep 'link/ether' | grep -vE '02:42:ac' | awk '{print $2}'ip a | grep 'link/ether' | grep -vE '02:42:ac' | awk '{print $2}'```

Comment: Thanks Bloch, this work for docker. But if there are virtual address created by some other application. It would difficult. Is there a generic filter?

Comment: seems that only by using the /sys/class/net, the `ip` cmdlet doesn't know which one is virtual.

Comment: windows `wmic` provides an useful option called `PhysicalAdapter=true` which will return on Physical MACs. I was looking for some thing similar in linux.

Comment: not my comfort zone, but could ARP table help?